# WPF window doesn't render content until resized?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple WPF dialog that shows any errors that occurred in the program.  The view model it's bound to is very simple, just a text property and a list property that displays the list of errors.  However, when I show this dialog in my application it shows up as empty, it's just the title bar and a completely white window.  As soon as I resize the window all the content populates properly.  Why would this be?  Here is the constructor of the window:

```
    public Wnd_Errors(string description, List<GamutError> ers)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _myVM = new ErrorWindowVM()
        {
            DescriptionText = description,
            Errors = ers,
        };
        DataContext = _myVM;
    }
```

Here is the entire XAML of the window:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" x:Class="SPTR.Gamut.Wnd_Errors" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Title="Gamut | Errors"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Icon="Images/Icon_Gamut.ico"
        Height="442" Width="846">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="SPECtrumStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource br_RibbonBackdrop}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="Images/Icon_Error.png" Margin="10" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="tb_Desc" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5" Text="{Binding DescriptionText}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Grid>
        <telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
                             CanUserFreezeColumns="False" EditTriggers="None" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" 
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Errors}" CanUserSelect="False">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Error Type" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ErrorTypeText}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Message" DataMemberBinding="{Binding UIText}"
                                            TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="*" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Internal Error" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ErrorTypeText}">
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ScrollViewer MaxWidth="800" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding InternalMessage, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Stack Trace" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ErrorTypeText}"
                                            IsVisible="{Binding ShowStackTrace}">
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="250" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Stack, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Content="Show Stack Trace (for error reporting)" 
                  IsChecked="{Binding ShowStackTrace, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,3" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Background="{StaticResource br_BaseBar}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="48*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="371*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Column="1">
                <Button Margin="5" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" IsDefault="True" 
                        x:Name="btn_OK" Click="btn_OK_Click" />
                <Button Margin="5" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" IsCancel="True" 
                        x:Name="btn_Cancel" Click="btn_Cancel_Click" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Export to .xlsx" Width="100" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    x:Name="Button2" Click="Button2_Click" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        </Grid>
        <Separator Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="-1" Background="{StaticResource Br_Orange}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see I don't even subscribe to any of the window events to have any type of custom handler that could be suppressing anything...

Where do I even start trying to debug this?  This is the only window in the application that does this (at least the only one I've encountered it with).

Comment: You might want to narrow it down to the source of the problem by setting break point on getters of those properties. Also, you can comment the styling to narrow down the source. Another thing, you may want to try is, set height and width of the grid itself.

Comment: I did put break points in the getters and they are being hit.  I will try the grid size and the commenting... thanks

Comment: I had these same issues because I had enabled `ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND`. The issues went away when I set `AllowTransparency` to true on the window.